# How extend Unity3d editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity3d in game development.
For every project I can extend editor.
How to extend Unity3d editor (for all projects, not for custom project)?

Comment: You **can not**.  It's just one of those annoying things about Unity. Simply drop your files in to Unity each time.  If you really want to, make it a package as Bart explains nicely.  There's no other way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no real way to make a permanent extension (i.e. an extension that is there for every new project). You can however [export your extension as a Unity package](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/HOWTO-exportpackage.html) and import this whenever you create a new project. As per the documenentation on the linked page:

> 1. In the Project View, select all the asset files you want to export.
> 2. Choose Assets->Export Package... from the menubar.
> 3. Name and save the package anywhere you like.
> 4. Open the project you want to bring the assets into.
> 5. Choose Assets->Import Package... from the menubar.
> 6. Select your package file saved in step 3.

That should be the simplest way to easily import your custom extensions into each project.

Comment: You can also place the unityPackage into Standard Assets folder (inside your unity installation folder), then the package will be listed in the Asset / Import Package list. *Note: When installing new version of unity, it will erase all the files from Unity installation folder, so need to copy it again..

Comment: It's worth pointing out that in 90% of cases ............. you just drop in the same source files in all your projects.  (Considering they will change all the time anyways.)  Unfortunately there is no, real, advantage in particularly using a package.

Answer (score 5):

For plugins intended to be used in many projects, but not changed in that project. Some people choose to build the plugin into a dll, then place the dll in the project rather than it's source code.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html

Answer (score 2):

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using System.IO;
public class MenuSystem : Editor 
{
[MenuItem("Backup/Take Backup")]
    public static void ExportBackUp()
    {
                string[] paths = new string[]
        {
            "Assets"
        };
        Debug.Log(paths);
        AssetDatabase.ExportPackage(paths, "Backup.unitypackage", ExportPackageOptions.Recurse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need, you can also use Property Drawers, introduced in Unity 4 it allows you to override your property's default inspector without writing a whole new inspector. And it works on both existing types or the custom ones you created.

You can even set variables in the attribute to customize the way you can edit each occurrence.

More informations here : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-PropertyDrawers.html

Comment: the OP is simply asking about how to do that "in many projects".